# How can I use <s:text> or any other tag instead of <s:textfield> in struts2?

Tags: jsp, select, struts2, popup

I have following text field in my jsp page. I have an edit button for this text field, which opens a popup and update the text field. I need to convert this  just like a text. When I used the `<s:text>` , I can't save the updated value to the DB, I am using struts2...

```xml
<s:textfield  maxlength="3" 
                   size="3" 
                   name="credentialExpiryDays" 
               readonly="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every Struts Tag is processed serverside: when it is rendered in the page (read: when a JSP is translated to an HTML), it becomes a standard HTML tag.

From that moment, forget about Struts tags.

Since the question is not completely clear:

1. If you want a textfield looking like a label while still being editable, use `cssStyle="border:none; background: transparent;"`;
2. If you want to turn a textfield into a label, you need to use Javascript, targeting the source object and replacing it with the new, desired HTML.